# fatal error: symbol '............' is multiply-defined

Tags: c++

I am new to oop and this is my first time doing a code involving double-linked list. As I finished and tried to compile my code, the following error appeared:

```
ld: fatal: symbol 'Character::MoveLeft(int)' is multiply-defined:
    (file /var/tmp//ccOhlQhs.o type=FUNC; file /var/tmp//cco5zfsu.o  type=FUNC);
ld: fatal: symbol 'Character::MoveRight(int)' is multiply-defined:
    (file /var/tmp//ccOhlQhs.o type=FUNC; file /var/tmp//cco5zfsu.o type=FUNC);
ld: fatal: symbol 'Character::getLetter()' is multiply-defined:
    (file /var/tmp//ccOhlQhs.o type=FUNC; file /var/tmp//cco5zfsu.o type=FUNC);
ld: fatal: symbol 'Character::Character()' is multiply-defined:
    (file /var/tmp//ccOhlQhs.o type=FUNC; file /var/tmp//cco5zfsu.o type=FUNC);
ld: fatal: symbol 'Character::Character()' is multiply-defined:
    (file /var/tmp//ccOhlQhs.o type=FUNC; file /var/tmp//cco5zfsu.o type=FUNC);
ld: fatal: symbol 'Character::setLetter(char)' is multiply-defined:
    (file /var/tmp//ccOhlQhs.o type=FUNC; file /var/tmp//cco5zfsu.o type=FUNC);
ld: fatal: symbol 'Character::Delete()' is multiply-defined:
    (file /var/tmp//ccOhlQhs.o type=FUNC; file /var/tmp//cco5zfsu.o type=FUNC);
ld: fatal: symbol 'Character::Insert(char)' is multiply-defined:
    (file /var/tmp//ccOhlQhs.o type=FUNC; file /var/tmp//cco5zfsu.o type=FUNC);
ld: fatal: file processing errors. No output written to a.out
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And the following are my header file and implementation file:

```
//lab3Character.h
1 #include <iostream>
2 #include <string>
3 
4 using namespace std;
5 
6 class Character{
7     private:
8 
9     char _letter;
10     Character* head;
11 
12     public:
13 
14     Character* next;
15     Character* prev;
16 
17     Character();
18     char getLetter();
19     void setLetter(char);
20     void MoveLeft(int);
21     void MoveRight(int);
22     void Insert(char);
23     void Delete();
24 
25 };
26 


//.cpp//
1 #include <iostream>
2 #include <string>
3 #include "lab3Character.h" 
4      
5 using namespace std;
6      
7 Character::Character(): _letter(0){
8     next = NULL;
9     prev = NULL;
10     head = NULL;
11 }
12 
13 char Character::getLetter(){ return _letter;} 
14 
15 void Character::setLetter(char cha){
16     _letter=cha;
17     return;
18 }   
19 
20 void Character::MoveLeft(int K) 
21 {
22     int i;
23 
24     for(i=1; i<=K; i++)
25     {
26         if(prev != NULL)
27         {
28             next = prev->next;
29             prev = prev->prev;
30         }
31         else
32             break;
33     }
34     return;
35 }
36 
37 void Character::MoveRight(int K)
38 {
39     int i;
40 
41     for(i=1; i<=K; i++)
42     {
43         if(next != NULL)
44         {
45             prev = next->prev;
46             next = next->next;
47         }
48 
49         else
50             break;
51     }
52 
53     return;
54 }
55 
56 void Character::Insert(char cha)
57 {
58 
59     if(head == NULL)
60     {
61       Character* newptr = new Character;
62         newptr->setLetter(cha);
63         head = newptr;
64         prev = newptr;
65 
66     }
67     else
68     {
69         Character* newnode = new Character;
70         newnode->setLetter(cha);
71         newnode->next = prev->next;
72         prev->next->prev = newnode;
73         prev->next = newnode;
74         newnode->prev = prev;
75 
76         if(newnode->prev == NULL)
77             head = newnode;
78 
79     }
80 
81     return;
82 }
83 
84 void  Character::Delete()
85 {
86     int i;
87 
88     if(prev == NULL)
89         return;
90 
91     else
92     {
93         prev->prev->next = prev->next;
94         prev = prev->prev;
95 
96         for(i=1; prev != NULL; i++)
97         {
98             next = prev->next;
99             prev = prev->prev;
100         }
101 
102         head = next->prev;
103 
104     }
105 
106     return;
107 }
108 
109 
110
```

Sorry for the long code and really appreciated for your help !

Comment: Show the command you're using to compile and link the program.

Comment: You are missing [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) in your header files.

Comment: You should really have `#include "lab3Character.h"` first as well. This will prevent needing the other includes in your cpp file as they will be included via your header.

Comment: The command I use: " g++ -g -Wall lab3Character.cpp Keyboard.cpp"          "keyboard.cpp" is my main function

Answer (score 0):

In your header file, add either

```
#pragma once
```

on the first line, or use

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

// Rest of your header file comes here

#endif
```

Hope this helps :)